# Javascript callback with nested filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Sounds basic but I cant get this callback correctly coded. I need the directory to be walked entirely and recursively. I need a list of the files that are 'm4v' only and also from that smaller array I need to probe the files to see what their frame heights are. Anything under 480p is too small and unacceptable. For this reason I would need to return this array of new files (conditions: m4v, under 480p) to the code that called this module.exports function.

file: frameHeightCheck.js
`lowResFilesOnDir.getAllFilesFromFolder(__dirname,function(res){
   // console.log(res);
});`

file: lowResFilesOnDir.getAllFilesFromFolder function exerpt

```
        var r = _.filter(filesystem.readdirSync(dir), function(file){
        var ext = file.split('.').pop();
        if(ext === 'm4v'){
           results = _.filter(results, function(f){
              probe(f, function(err,probeData){
                 var height = probeData.streams[1].height;
                 if(height > 479){
                    // acceptable height do not do anything
                 }
                 else {
                    return f;
                 }
              })
           })
           return results;
        }
     });
```

Another version I tried having both checks nested is:

```
     var r = _.filter(filesystem.readdirSync(dir), function(file){
        var ext = file.split('.').pop();
        if(ext === 'm4v'){
              probe(file, function(err,probeData){
                 var height = probeData.streams[1].height;
                 if(height > 479){
                    // acceptable height do not do anything
                 }
                 else {
                    return file;
                 }
              })
        }
     });
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo on the 2nd line. 
I believe you were looking to do this instead:
`var ext = files.split('.').pop()`

Comment: In case you didn't pick it up, files should be plural as per the callback arguments?

Comment: `_.filter(results,` did you mean to use the variable `files` here? Also the extension check probably should be inside the `filter()` call as well

Comment: Yeah, I would say as a whole this looks good but it appears that you have a few typos that could get this thing working. Take a look at my comment and @PatrickEvans

Comment: sorry guys didnt notice the typos but even after fixing these, which i had already done in my own troubleshooting, still doesnt work.